# How do i exit a loop when user enters null

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I need to write a program that prompts the user to to enter up to 5 movie titles. User to hit enter to exit input and partially fill array.

I've tried many solutions suggested in these pages. Either the loop continues or i get boolean/string conversion errors.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String [] Movie = new String[5];
      String title;
      int count = 0;
      for(int i=0; i < Movie.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Movie titles (enter null to exit)"); 
         while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            if(sc.equals("")) {
               break;
            }
            title = sc.nextLine();
            Movie[i] = title;
            count++;
         }                  
      }      
      for(int i=0; i < Movie.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(Movie[i]);      
      }
   }
```

I expect the program to input code until user hits enter then see output of what was entered.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are comparing `Scanner` object with empty `String` which is wrong `sc.equals("")`. First read the input into String and them check empty or not

```
for(int i=0; i < Movie.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Movie titles (enter null to exit)"); 
     while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        title = sc.nextLine();
        if(title.equals("")) {
           break;
        }

        Movie[i] = title;
        count++;
     }                  
  }
```

To just print an array use `Arrays.toString`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Movie));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and i changed my code to this. However the enter 5 titles println starts up and i want it output the array

Answer (score 0):

You should not nest two loops for reading the input, you need one loop with two conditions; the count must be less than the `Movies` array length (which should be named `movies` to follow Java naming conventions) and there needs to be another line for the `Scanner`. I would prefer `String.isEmpty()` to `String.equals("")`. And your second loop should stop at `count` (since entries after that are potentially blank). Something like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] movies = new String[5];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < movies.length && sc.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Movie titles (enter null to exit)");
    String title = sc.nextLine();
    if (title.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    movies[count] = title;
    count++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    System.out.println(movies[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I changed my code to this and the  first println did not show.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class MovieTitles
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String Movie[] = new String [10];
      for(int i = 0 ; i < Movie.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Enter up to 10 Movie titles (enter null to exit). Title " + (i + 1));
         String title = sc.nextLine();
         if(title.matches("")) {
            break;            
        }else {
           Movie[i] = title;
        }
     }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Movie)); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is the closest i have come. toString prints the full array including nulls so i will probably change that. I came up with title.matches after looking through the title. options. The while loop would not work at all, maybe its a boolean thing. Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class MovieTitles
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String Movie[] = new String [10];
      int count = 0;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < Movie.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Enter up to 10 Movie titles (enter null to exit). Title " + (i + 1));
         String title = sc.nextLine();
         if(title.matches("")) {
            break;            
        }else {
           Movie[i] = title;
           count++;
        }
     }
      System.out.println("Movie Titles:\n");
      for(int j = 0 ; j < count; j++)         
      System.out.printf("%s\n", Movie[j]); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is the final answer i achieved after agonising over this the whole weekend. I went back to basics and got one part working the way i wanted and then built on that, retracing modifications that did not work or suit. Hope this helps others with the same problem. Very satisfying to get a result.